# jQuery function gets called twice for each click

Tags: jquery

**Setup:**

I have written a jQuery function to update table cells of table_2, when a row in table_1 is clicked. Here is what I have written:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("tr").live('click',function() {
            var host = $(this);
            alert('A row in table 1 is clicked!');

            var count = host.find("td").eq(2).text();
            $("#myTable_2 tr:eq(0) td:eq(1)").text(count);
            $("#myTable_2 tr:eq(1) td:eq(1)").text(5);
        });
    </script>
```

**The Problem:**

When I step-through this function using FireBug, I can see the cell data in myTable_2 is being changed. BUT, for every click, the function is executed twice. I can see the alert box appearing twice for each click.

Can somebody tell me why does this happen? And how to avoid this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Either of the following:

1. The clicked row is inside another row (two rows are clicked). ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/6UmpY/))
2. The code you've shown is executed twice ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/6UmpY/1/)).

To solve this, make your selector more specific. If you're using jQuery 1.7+, use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `live`: http://jsfiddle.net/6UmpY/3/

```
$(document).on("click", "#myTable_1 > tbody > tr", function() {
    // This selector will only match direct rows of the myTable_1 table
```

Note: Using `.on` instead of `live` did not solve the problem.
Using a more specific selector *did* fix the issue.
If you love `live`, the following would also work: http://jsfiddle.net/6UmpY/4/

```
$("#myTable_1 > tbody > tr").live("click", function() {
```

Answer (score 12):

just simply avoid the propagation of the click

```
$("tr").live('click',function() {

        ...

        $( event.toElement ).one('click', function(e){ e.stopImmediatePropagation(); } );
    });
```

Comment: Are there any potential negative consequences of doing this?

Comment: This stops anything else listening to the event on the element receiving the event. Events are called in the order they are added and only events added after this one will be prevented.

Answer (score 3):

assume `table_1` is the id of first table.

```
$("#table_1 tbody").on('click','tr', function() {
            var host = $(this);
            alert('A row in table 1 is clicked!');

            var count = host.find("td").eq(2).text();
            $("#myTable_2 tr:eq(0) td:eq(1)").text(count);
            $("#myTable_2 tr:eq(1) td:eq(1)").text(5);
        });
```

**NOTE:**  `live()` has been deprecated, so write like above.  you code execute twice because `tr` selector belongs to both tables and event bind twice.

You can also use `delegate()`:

```
$("#table_1 tbody").delegate("tr", "click", function(){
     var host = $(this);
     alert('A row in table 1 is clicked!');
     var count = host.find("td").eq(2).text();
     $("#myTable_2 tr:eq(0) td:eq(1)").text(count);
     $("#myTable_2 tr:eq(1) td:eq(1)").text(5);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So you mean using 'on' or `delegate` will solve the problem of function getting called twice?

Comment: @Learner no `on()` is used to bind event in from jquery 1.7+, and twice event fire will solve by using `#table_1`, because it will select only `tr` that belongs to first table

Answer (score 0):

It is because 
 $("tr").live('click',function() {});
   ^^^^^ has 2 counts in the html.
To ensure .live () or .delegate() is executed once, the selector in $(selector).delegate() is better to be "$(table[name=users])" rather than $('td') or $('tr')

Answer (score 0):

Some elements may have the same properties (class name, tag name ect.) wich you may overlook. This can cause such a conflict. In the example below the "tr" element is used as the selector for the alert, but the script has two nested "tr" elements that contain the "text" target. Thus, with a single click you get an alert fired for each (from inside out) "tr" element seperately. This is called [bubbling](http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing). You could simply use [stopPropogation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) to stop the [bubbling](http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing).

```
$("tr").live('click',function() {
    alert('A row in table 1 is clicked!');
    event.stopPropogation();
});

<table>
  **<tr>**
    <td>    
      <table id="myTable_1">
        **<tr>**
         <td>Test</td>
        **</tr>**
      </table>
    </td>
  **</tr>**
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6UmpY/97/